# appending multiple datasets from the same excel

Tags: excel, date, dataset, append, openxlsx

After uploading into r (with openxlsx) an excel with hundreds of tabs I am left with hundreds of dataframes with 6-9 variables each.

The name of each tab (now dataset) is a date (like 080720).

1. How do I append them all (they are hundreds) in one individual dataset
   and
2. (if possible) add a variable column with the name of their original dataset (the date)?

Comment: how are you reading in the wb? Is it putting each sheet into a separate list? What does the code look like to import?